# javaScript - button with a "click" event listener is triggering mulitple times if clicked fast enough

Tags: javascript, event-listener

im trying to make an image slider (carousel) and it is working ok, but when I click the previous or next button fast enough, the event listener starts firing multiple times and the image slider stops functioning correctly.

here is the javaScript

```
const PREV = document.getElementById("prev");
const NEXT = document.getElementById("next");

let slideIndex = 1;
showSlide(slideIndex);

function changeSlide(n) {
    showSlide((slideIndex += n));
    
}

function showSlide(n) {
    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("quote");
    let pictures = document.getElementsByClassName("picture");

    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
    }

    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++) {
        pictures[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    pictures[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}

PREV.addEventListener("click", () => {
    changeSlide(-1);
});

NEXT.addEventListener("click", () => {
    changeSlide(1);
});
```

*edit: after messing around more, I found that the problem is related to the browser im using (firefox) and screen size...when in responsive mode and the viewport is set to mobile size (375px - 414px) the problem is occurring, but if i make the screen bigger than than 414px it seems to be working as it should...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid that, you need something like this:

```js
let timeout;

function debouncedFunction(callback, time){
  if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout)

  timeout = setTimeout(() => callback(), time)
}
```

this will override timeout and only call the function when the time passes without clicks